# Show $\sin x = bx$ has at least 3 real solutions.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Show $\sin x=bx$ has at least 3 real solutions for every $b$, where $-\dfrac{2}{3 \pi} < b < \dfrac{2}{\pi}$.

Some useful facts I am trying to use:

Intermediate value theorem: If $f$ is a continuous real-valued function on $[a,b]$ and $d \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(a)< d< f(b)$, then there exists a point $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f(c) = d$.

Corollary: If $f$ is a continuous real-valued function on $[a,b]$, then $f([a,b])$ is a closed interval.

Comment: Have you plotted all of $\sin x$, $2x/\pi$ and $-2x/3\pi$ in the same figure? I would not think about a problem like this without doing that first.

Comment: Are you sure that $\,-\frac{2}{3}\pi<b< \frac{2}{\pi}\,$? Perhaps in the right hand it should be $\,2\pi\,$...?

Comment: @DonAntonio: I'm fairly sure the $2/3\pi$ means the same number as $2/(3\pi)$. I would write it that way myself! If I intended $(2/3)\pi$, I would write it $2\pi/3$ instead.

Comment: That seems sound, @JyrkiLahtonen...yet one cannot be completely sure with the way some people use to write styff in this site...

Comment: sorry about the notation, it is 2/(3$\pi$)

Comment: Another hint: both sides of your equation are odd functions of $x$, so if $x$ is a solution, $-x$ is another. Zero is one solution, where might you look for others? And draw that damn graph!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $\sin x=bx$ has the obvious solution $x=0$. Since $\sin(-x)=-\sin x$, if $x$ is a solution, so is $-x$. Thus if we can find at least one non-zero solution, then there are at least $2$ non-zero solutions: we can reflect across the $y$-axis. This will give us the desired "at least three."

So all we need to do is to show that if $0\le b\lt \frac{2}{\pi}$, there is at least one non-zero solution, and that if $-\frac{2}{3\pi}\lt b\lt 0$, there is at least one non-zero solution.  Actually, we can do better than $\frac{2}{\pi}$: there is in fact a non-zero solution for any $b$ with $-\frac{2}{3\pi}\le b\lt 1$.

Let $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ when $x\ne 0$, and $f(0)=1$. Since $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, the function $f(x)$ is **continuous** everywhere.

Deal first with $0\le b\lt 1$. The case $b=0$ is trivial, we can take $x=n\pi$ for any positive integer $n$. Since $f(\pi)=0$, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, for any $b$ such that $1\gt b\gt 0$, there is a $c$ between $0$ and $\pi$ such that $f(c)=b$, that is, $\sin c=bc$.

Now we deal with negative $b$. We have $f(\pi)=0$ and $f(3\pi/2)=-\frac{2}{3\pi}$. So again by the Intermediate Value Theorem, for any $b$ with $-\frac{2}{3\pi}\lt b\lt 0$, there is a $c$ between $\pi$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ such that $\sin c=bc$.

This completes the proof. We have actually shown that if $-\frac{2}{3\pi}\le b\lt 1$, there is a non-zero $c$ (and therefore at least two non-zero $c$) such that 
$\sin c=bc$.

Comment: f(0) = 1, not 0.

Comment: Thank you, fixed. Sharp eyes!

Answer (score 0):

Change it a bit to
$f(x) =\sin(x)/x = b$.
Since this is symmetrical
($f(x) = f(-x)$),
any solution to $f(x) = b$
causes another solution $f(-x) = b$.
The solutions, therefore, come in pairs.
I will therefore only look at positive solutions,
and the total number of solutions
will be double this.

To find how large $b$ can be,
look at the extreme values of $f(x)$.

$f'(x) = (\sin(x) - x \cos(x))/x^2$,
so the extreme values are at
the $x$ such that
$\sin(x) - x \cos(x) = 0$
or $\tan(x) = x$.

This can only be solved numerically
(aside from $x = 0$ when $f(x) = 1$),
so I will do that.

Note that
$f(\pi/2) = 1/(\pi/2) = 2/\pi$ and
$f(3\pi/2) = -1/(3\pi/2)=-2/(3\pi)$,
which is presumably where the original problem
got these values.
However, these are not the values
at the first extremes, but they are close, 
as we will see.

If $0 \le b < 1$,
there is one positive solution
to $f(x) = b$
since $1 = f(0) > b > 0 = f(\pi)$.
If there are any more solutions,
they are between
$2\pi$ and $3\pi$,
since $f(x) < 0$ for
$\pi < x < 2\pi$.

To have such a solution,
$b$ is as most
$f(x_1)$, where $x_1$ is
the root of $\tan(x) = x$
that is between
$2\pi$ and $3\pi$.

Numerically, this is $x_1=7.725252...$
and $f(x_1) = 0.12837...... = 0.4033.../\pi$.
If $0 < b < f(x_1)$,
$f(x) = b$ has at least 3 positive roots
(and so at least 6 roots total);
if $f(x_1) < b < 1$,
$f(x) = b$ has only 1 positive root
(and so only 2 roots total).

For $b < 0$,
we look where $\sin(x) < 0$;
this is $\pi < x < 2\pi$.

The root $x_2$ in this interval
is, numerically, $x_2=4.49340...$
and $f(x_2) = -0.2172... = -0.682.../\pi$.
If $0 > b > f(x_2)$,
then $f(x) = b$ has at least 2 positive roots
(which surround $x_2$)
and so has at least 4 roots total.

To see which values of $b$
have only 2 positive roots
(although this was not in the problem),
we look in the interval
$3\pi < x < 4\pi$.

The root $x_3$ in this interval
is, numerically, $x_3=10.9041...$
and $f(x_3) = -0.09132... = -0.2869.../\pi$.
If $0 > b > f(x_3)$,
then $f(x) = b$ has at least 4 positive roots
(and so at least 8 real roots);
if $f(x_2) > b > f(x_3)$,
then $f(x) = b$ has exactly 2 positive roots
(and so only 4 real roots).

I therefore question the question.

Comment: The question said **at least** $3$ roots.

Answer (score 0):

if $b = 0$, there are infinitely many solutions;

otherwise, note that for $x = \pm\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have $|\sin x| = 1$ while $|bx|<1$; but as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$ we have $|\sin x| \le 1$ while $|bx|\rightarrow\infty$; by the intermediate value theorem, the (continuous) function $|\sin x| - |bx|$ vanishes for some $|x| > \frac{\pi}{2}$; this gives a pair ($\pm$) of nonzero solutions

Answer (score 0):

The equation $\sin x = bx$ has at least three solutions for every $b \in [0,1)$ because $\sin x$ has decreasing slope at any value $x \in (0, \pi)$, therefore any straight line with slope $b \in [0, 1)$ will intersect $\sin x$ somewhere in $x \in (0, \pi)$, and also at $-x$ because $\sin$ is an odd function.

And since $1 \gt 2/\pi$, then if $0\lt b \lt 2/\pi$, $b$ is a solution.
The smallest value of $b$ such that $\sin x = bx$ is some number such that $bx$ is tangent to $\sin x$ on the interval $x \in (\pi, 2\pi)$ The point of tangency occurs at some value $x = g, g\in (\pi, 2pi)$. $b$ and $g$ can be related to each other by the system of equations $\sin g = bg, \cos g = b$. This system has infinitely many solutions, but only one with $g \in (\pi, 2\pi)$ This value $g$ is about $4.4934094579...$ and $b$ ~ $-0.2172..$. 
Therefore if $b \in (-.2172..., 1)$, $\sin x = bx$ must have at least three solutions.
This approximation of $b$ is slightly more negative than $-2/3\pi$ ~ $-.2122...$, so if $b\in [-2/3\pi, 2/\pi]$, $\sin x = bx$ must have at least three solutions.